# future simple or progressive or present

Tags: grammar, tense

Please take a look at this internet chat between a seller and a buyer;

> Buyer:Already paid 19,75 +16,75 = 36,6 So I have a credit of about 11 USD, if you could add the watermelon split 7" it would be fine, if not paypaled 10,5 to me.
>
> Seller:Sounds good, let's hope that it doesn't push the weight to much.
>
> Seller answered after he had checked the split's weight :I WILL be including the watermelon split7".

My question is why future continuous ? Why not simple future or present progressive  It is a kind of arrangement as I asked for it first.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific reason for it. This seems quite informal chatter, so the seller's probably not putting a lot of thought into what they're saying, and after all, it's understandable. Sometimes people just be funny.

Comment: Don't you think it is to emphasize the action of including

Comment: No. He's capitalised 'will' to emphasise the including, but he could just as easily have said 'I SHALL include the...' to provide the same emphasis.

Answer (score 2):

So, you've suggested three options the seller could choose from:

> (A) I *will* be including the watermelon split 7". 
>   (B) I *will* include the watermelon split 7". 
>   (C) I *am* including the watermelon split 7".

All three of these are fine, but I think (A) is best. The downside of (B) is that it doesn't exactly sound like a neutral statement of fact, but rather like a promise (or a threat, though not in this case); and the downside of (C) is that it could make it sound like he has already started putting together the package, whereas in fact he had merely made a decision about it.